# How to get percent of each category on given date with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Giving a try at Pyspark and struggling.

I've got this here...

```
internal_pct_by_day = df_resampled.groupBy('dt_resampled', 'traffic_source').count()
internal_pct_by_day.show(5)

+-------------------+--------------+-----+
|       dt_resampled|traffic_source|count|
+-------------------+--------------+-----+
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             2|  320|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             1|   84|
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             2|   66|
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             3|    4|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             3|    1|
+-------------------+--------------+-----+
```

I originally had many records at unique times and I 'resampled' them by day.  Now my table shows that 320 visitors came via traffic source 2 on the 13th and 4 visitors came via traffic source 3 on the 14th, etc.

Now I am trying to add columns to show what percent of visitors came from each source for each day.

The ideal solution would look like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------+-----+
|       dt_resampled|traffic_source|count| //total   //percent
+-------------------+--------------+-----+
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             2|  320| //405     //79%
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             1|   84| //405     //20%
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             2|   66| //70      //94% 
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             3|    4| //70      //6%
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             3|    1| //405     //1%
+-------------------+--------------+-----+
```

I mangled some code from stack overflow and came up with this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank,sum,col
from pyspark.sql import Window

window = Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)

grouped_df = df_resampled\
.groupBy('dt_resampled', 'traffic_source')\
.agg(F.sum('traffic_source').alias('sum_traffic_source'))\
.withColumn('total', sum(col('sum_traffic_source')).over(window))\
.withColumn('percent',col('sum_traffic_source')*100/col('total'))

grouped_df.show(5)

+-------------------+--------------+------------------+-----+-------------------+
|       dt_resampled|traffic_source|sum_traffic_source|total|            percent|
+-------------------+--------------+------------------+-----+-------------------+
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             2|               640|  896|  71.42857142857143|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             1|                84|  896|              9.375|
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             2|               132|  896| 14.732142857142858|
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             3|                12|  896| 1.3392857142857142|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             3|                 3|  896|0.33482142857142855|
+-------------------+--------------+------------------+-----+-------------------+
```

I can't seem to get quite what I want.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 0:** Importing the relevant functions

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, col, round
```

**Step 1:** Creating the relevant dataframe.

```
valuesCol = [('2016-06-13 20:00:00',2,320),('2016-06-13 20:00:00',1,84),('2016-06-14 20:00:00',2,66),
             ('2016-06-14 20:00:00',3,4),('2016-06-13 20:00:00',3,1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valuesCol,['dt_resampled','traffic_source','count'])
# Cast the string to proper timestamp
df = df.withColumn('dt_resampled',to_timestamp(col('dt_resampled'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))    
df.show()
+-------------------+--------------+-----+
|       dt_resampled|traffic_source|count|
+-------------------+--------------+-----+
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             2|  320|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             1|   84|
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             2|   66|
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             3|    4|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             3|    1|
+-------------------+--------------+-----+
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- dt_resampled: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- traffic_source: long (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = true)
```

**Step 2:** Calculating total traffic per day. In order to write familiar `SQL` syntax to operate on a `DataFrame`, we have to first register it as `temporary SQL view`, as done in the first line below -

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('table_view')
df=sqlContext.sql(
    'select dt_resampled, traffic_source, count, sum(count) over (partition by dt_resampled) as total_per_day from table_view'
)
df = df.withColumn('percent', round(col('count')/col('total_per_day'),4))
df.show()
+-------------------+--------------+-----+-------------+-------+
|       dt_resampled|traffic_source|count|total_per_day|percent|
+-------------------+--------------+-----+-------------+-------+
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             2|   66|           70| 0.9429|
|2016-06-14 20:00:00|             3|    4|           70| 0.0571|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             2|  320|          405| 0.7901|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             1|   84|          405| 0.2074|
|2016-06-13 20:00:00|             3|    1|          405| 0.0025|
+-------------------+--------------+-----+-------------+-------+
```

Precision of `percent` can be changed by specifying the second argument of `round()` function accordingly.

Comment: It worked!  I read up on 'partition by' and will utilize that in the future.  Thank you!

Comment: Pleasure, I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby`

like this

```
df['total'] = df['dt_resampled'].map(df.groupby('dt_resampled')['count'].sum()) 
df['percent'] = df['count']/df['total']*100

          dt_resampled  traffic_source  count  total    percent
0  2016-06-13 20:00:00               2    320    405  79.012346
1  2016-06-13 20:00:00               1     84    405  20.740741
2  2016-06-14 20:00:00               2     66     70  94.285714
3  2016-06-14 20:00:00               3      4     70   5.714286
4  2016-06-13 20:00:00               3      1    405   0.246914
```

Comment: Nice simple answer!  But I get this error... thoughts?  `'GroupedData' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I did this to turn my unique timestamps into 'days' `df_resampled = df.withColumn('dt_resampled', resample(df.timestamp, agg_interval=(60*60*24)))`

Comment: This answer is for a pandas dataframe. The syntax is different for pyspark dataframes.

Comment: you could first make a copy of the dataframe to a pandas object? maybe @pault is right

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that will help, the DataFrame is pretty huge, so I'm required to use spark apis.  Thank you though.

Comment: @JoseAngelSanchez When the dataset is huge, converting to pandas directly may turn out to be highly inefficient, not to mention that if you are using `spark`, then it's fair to exploit it's data distribution framework to speed up the things. Distrubution across the cluster won't happen on pandas dataframe.